# Is this kind of inverse substitution justified?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, inequality, integral-inequality

I'm trying to prove that for every integer $n\geq 0$ we have
$$\int_0^{\pi/2} (1+\cos t)^ndt\geq \frac{2^{n+1}-1}{n+1}.$$
I started out by rewriting the RHS as
$\int_0^{1}(1+x)^ndx$ and substituting $x=\cos t$, where $t$ ranges from
$\pi/2$ to $0$. Then $dx=-\sin t dt$ and we get
$$\int_{\pi/2}^0(1+\cos t)^n (-\sin t)dt = \int_0^{\pi/2}(1+\cos t)^n \sin t dt
\leq \int_0^{\pi/2}(1+\cos t)^n dt,$$
where in the equality I took out the minus sign from the $\sin$ to
flip the limits of integration. What seems suspicious to me though is how $t$ ranges from the larger value $\pi/2$ to $0$: is this ok? I tried doing different substitutions like $x=\cos t$ but for $-\pi/2\leq t\leq 0$ but I couldn't recover what I wanted from these.

Comment: The bounds can be in the wrong order, that's fine. You then change the sign of the integrand when you reverse the bounds. I see no problem with your approach

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Put
$$x=1+\cos(t)$$
with
$$dx=-\sin(t)$$

Your integral satisfies

$$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}(1+\cos(t))^ndt\ge \int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}(1+\cos(t))^n\sin(t)dt$$

because
$$(\forall t\in[0,\frac{\pi}{2}])\;\;\; 0\le\sin(t)\le 1$$

With the substitution above, the right integral becomes

$$-\int_2^1x^ndx=\int_1^2x^ndx=\Bigl[\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}\Bigr]_1^2$$